# Jquery.height() return 0 for an img tag

Tags: jquery, height

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.full.js"></script>
<body>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var jdialog = $('<div id="avatar_button_clipdiv" style="width: 668px; height: 425px">\
<img width="668" height="900" src="http://localhost/1_tmp.jpg" style="">\
</div>').appendTo('body');
    console.log(jdialog.find('img'));
    console.log(jdialog.find('img').width(),jdialog.find('img').height());
</script>
```

This code works fine after I put it alone in another file,the height() returns the right value instead of 0,but when I put it back into the full HTML file,it returns 0 instead of its real value,it is weired and do not have any idea on what could possiblely make it act differently.

I've edited some CSS file before I run this code,can not remember what lines of css I had edited.The selectors are correct and I've checked the return object,nothing wrong either in the seperate code or the original HTML file.Can anyone shed some light on what css changes could make this kind of difference while using $().height();

**EDIT**

**I've spot on the following css code and after I commented them ,the height can be retrieved correctly,but still have no idea why this is happening,here is the code**

```
img {
  width: auto\9;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 0;
  -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
}
```

height: auto; is what I've commneted out,but how is height:auto effected with $().height();

Answer (score 0):

The code you shared by itself seems to do the job
I even ran it in a [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/axMJn/):

```
var jdialog = $('<div id="avatar_button_clipdiv" style="width: 68px; height: 125px">\
<img width="50" height="100" src="https://www.google.co.il/images/srpr/logo4w.png" style=""/>\
</div>').appendTo('body');
console.log(jdialog.find('img'));
console.log(jdialog.find('img').width(),jdialog.find('img').height());
```

does this happes on a specific browser?

Comment: No,it happens the same in all browser,the code above works fine,but after I put it back to the original html file,the height is 0,the width() is right though,I do not know why

Answer (score 0):

```
var $img = jdialog.find('img');    
$img.load(function(){
    console.log($img.height());
});
```

Comment: Nothing returns,even not 0

Answer (score 0):

When all else fails read the actual height attribute like so:

```
var height = jdialog.find('img').attr('height');
```

But if you need the real computed height try using [imagesloaded](http://desandro.github.io/imagesloaded/) to execute the measuring function only when the needed image is fully loaded.
Conventional 'load' or 'ready' events break with cached images.